# MySQL sorting by repetitive pattern

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of products in MySQL table like this:

```
id_manufacturer | id_product
1                 1
2                 5
3                 6
4                 10
1                 14
2                 18
3                 25
4                 27
1                 28
2                 29
3                 30
4                 35
1                 40
2                 42
3                 45
4                 55
```

My desired outcome is to get back list of products ordered by manufacturer grouped by manufacturer but only 3 of each and then repeat the pattern again:

```
id_manufacturer | id_product
1                 1
1                 14
1                 28
2                 5
2                 29
2                 18
3                 6
3                 25
3                 30
4                 27
4                 35
4                 10
1                 154
1                 145
1                 285
```

Can someone help please?

Thank you!

Comment: post your request code

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested queries with local variables.
Try this:

```
select 
    id_manufacturer, 
    id_product
from (
                select 
                    id_manufacturer, 
                    id_product,
                    case when (@prev_id <> id_manufacturer) then (@num := 1) else (@num := @num + 1) end as dummy1,
                    (@prev_id := id_manufacturer) as dummy2,
                    @num as rownum
                from tbl, (select @prev_id := -1, @num := 0) x
                order by 
                    id_manufacturer asc, 
                    id_product asc
) subq
where
    rownum <= 3
```